# Storm UI getting Internal Server Error :org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

When I try connect to the storm ui, the web show me that

```
org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at backtype.storm.thrift$nimbus_client_and_conn.invoke(thrift.clj:75)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$all_topologies_summary.invoke(core.clj:493)
    at backtype.storm.ui.core$fn__8227.invoke(core.clj:793)
    at compojure.core$make_route$fn__3365.invoke(core.clj:93)
    at compojure.core$if_route$fn__3353.invoke(core.clj:39)
    at compojure.core$if_method$fn__3346.invoke(core.clj:24)
    at compojure.core$routing$fn__3371.invoke(core.clj:106)
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2443)
    at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:106)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at compojure.core$routes$fn__3375.invoke(core.clj:111)
```

Zookeeper also started and connection zookeeper connected in storm like storm.ymal

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "localhost"
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Zookeeper's default port is 2181. Did you check it is open?

Comment: it sounds like you've installed package `zookeeper`, but not `zookeeperd`

Comment: I had same issue .I had set this property wrong. storm.local.dir:<path>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `nimbus.host`, is it set from default `nimbus` to something real host?

```
  1 ########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration                                                                                                               
  2  storm.zookeeper.servers:                                                                           
  3      - "localhost"                                                                                  
  4 #                                                                                                   
  5  nimbus.host: "localhost"                                                                           
  6 #                                                                                                   
  7 #                                                                                                   
  8 # ##### These may optionally be filled in:                                                          
  9 #                                                                                                   
 10 ## List of custom serializations                                                                    
 11 # topology.kryo.register:                                                                           
 12 #     - org.mycompany.MyType                                                                        
 13 #     - org.mycompany.MyType2: org.mycompany.MyType2Serializer                                      
 14 #                                                                                                   
 15 ## List of custom kryo decorators                                                                   
 16 # topology.kryo.decorators:                                                                         
 17 #     - org.mycompany.MyDecorator                                                                   
 18 #                                                                                                   
 19 ## Locations of the drpc servers                                                                    
 20 # drpc.servers:                                                                                     
 21 #     - "server1"                                                                                   
 22 #     - "server2"
```